# entering a string instead of an integer in a calendar in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

My code goes like this:

```
import sys 
import calendar

trueVal = 'yes' 
while trueVal ==  'yes' :  

 yy = int(input("Enter year: ")) #input should be a string 
 mm = int(input("Enter month: "))

 print(calendar.month(yy, mm))#returns the result

 cmd=input("Would you like to view another calendar? Type yes if you do, no to exit program") 


 if cmd != trueVal :
  sys.exit()
```

it actually works, but my prof said
"Fix it. Try entering a string instead of an integer",
so I tried replacing the `int` to `str`
knowing that I'm a notorious beginner, it gave me an error (which I expected nevertheless).

I got some advices that said that the output must be converted to str as well, how can I do that?

Comment: are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: so i clarified my prof abt what she required. she wactually wanted me to make an extra line of code that states an error if the input is not integer. example, if the user inputs an integer.

Comment: oh and im using python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Use instead of int() own function:

```
def myint(s):
  try:
    return int(s)
  except:
    print("Input '%s' does not look like integer")
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following code:

```
import sys
import calendar

trueVal = 'yes'

while trueVal ==  'yes':
    yy = input("Enter year: ") #input should be a string
    mm = input("Enter month: ")
    print(calendar.month(int(yy), int(mm)))#returns the result
    cmd = input("Would you like to view another calendar? Type yes if you do, no to exit program")

    if cmd != trueVal:
        sys.exit()
```

Your input would be string and is casted to int inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

[image] Calendar.month method takes only integers but you are giving string values.